# Can't open properties and any .cs form

Tags: visual-studio, file, properties

I get this error message, when i load project and i'm tring to open a view desing, view code or properties:
[image]

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a323b85-d10f-45f5-83b6-cc9a9b1ba707/vs2010-project-configuration-properties-editing-crashes?forum=vssetup) can help you. There are some possible causes for the problem.

Comment: That is a VS2002 version number.  You are asking this question 14 years too late.  How this could happen on an OS that is clearly not XP is something you'll have to explain, nobody could guess at that.